# group_concat in separate columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a players table

```
id  name
--  ----
1   jack
2   john
3   mike
4   pikachu
```

And I have a matches table where these players can be matched together.

```
id pair_id player_id
-- ------- ---------
 1       1         1
 2       1         2
 3       2         3
 4       2         4
```

So I tried something like `select group_concat(name) group by pair_id` 
The end results is something like:

```
names
---------
Jack,John
```

But what I like to is to get players in their own columns like:

```
p1   p2
---- ----
Jack John
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Search for 'pivot'.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you do not want group_concat() at all, you want a join:

```
SELECT t1.name AS p1, t2.name AS p2
FROM
    players AS t1
INNER JOIN
    matches m1 ON t1.id = m1.player_id
INNER JOIN
    matches m2 ON m1.pair_id = m2.pair_id and m1.id < m2.id
INNER JOIN
    players t2 ON t2.id = m2.player_id
```

The `m1.id < m2.id` part ensures that each pair will be returned only once, with `p1` being the one with smaller `id` in the `matches` table for a given `pair_id`.

Answer (score 1):

No `group_concat` needed, just joins:

```
select player1.name as p1, player2.name as p2
from matches m1
join players player1 on m1.player_id = player1.id
join matches m2 on m1.pair_id = m2.pair_id and m1.id != m2.id
join players player2 on m2.player_id = player2.id;
```